# Learning about using cookies for the first time in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I am brand new to PHP and I'm a little stuck and frustrated! I want this little simple site to display a different image every time the user reloads the page -using cookies in php.

I know my code is far from correct, but I really am hoping to receive a push in the right direction of how I can achieve my goal

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
function random_image(){
$rdmimg = array();
array_push($rdmimg, "/php/rollingpin.jpg");
array_push($rdmimg, "/php/candlestick.jpg");
array_push($rdmimg, "/php/table.jpg");
array_push($rdmimg, "/php/table2.jpg");
$output = rand(0, count($rdmimg) - 1);
echo $rdmimg[$output];
};
$a = random_image();
setcookie("check image", $checkimage);

$_COOKIE = $a;

if(isset($checkimage)
if ($_COOKIE == $a){
    $i = $i + 1;
            //I know $i isn't set, thinking of implementing somehow
}

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>JFQ Turnings</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000">
<img src="jfqturnings.gif" alt="JFQ Turnings, coming soon." width="864" height="100">
<br /><img src="<?php echo $a ?>" alt="" width="864" height="567">
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your responses!

Comment: You should be returning `$rdmimg[$output];` not echoing it.

Comment: I've never set a cookie prior to this code...should I set it to $a?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have 2 method used in the code above:

1. Selecting a random element from the array using `$output = rand(0, count($rdmimg) - 1);`.
2. Incrementing a variable to keep track of which image has been shown `$i = $i + 1;`.

I'd like to show how both methods may be implemented with heavily commented code.

1. If you're selecting a random element, the only issue would be making sure that the same image does not show up twice.

   ```
   function random_image() {
       $rdmimg = array();
       array_push($rdmimg, "/php/rollingpin.jpg");
       array_push($rdmimg, "/php/candlestick.jpg");
       array_push($rdmimg, "/php/table.jpg");
       array_push($rdmimg, "/php/table2.jpg");
       $output = $rdmimg[rand(0, count($rdmimg) - 1)]; //obtain the path of the image from the array
       return $output; //return instead of echoing
   }

   $checkimage = random_image();

   if (isset($_COOKIE['check_image'])) //if a cookie has been set
       while ($checkimage == $_COOKIE['check_image']) //keep attempting to get a random image that is not the current one
           $checkimage = random_image();

   setcookie("check_image", $checkimage);

   //make sure the below code is echo $checkimage NOT echo $a.
   ```
2. If instead you want to cycle through the images, you may try this approach instead:

   ```
   <?php

   $rdmimg = array();
   array_push($rdmimg, "/php/rollingpin.jpg");
   array_push($rdmimg, "/php/candlestick.jpg");
   array_push($rdmimg, "/php/table.jpg");
   array_push($rdmimg, "/php/table2.jpg");

   $count = intval($_COOKIE['check_image']); //convert to a number, strings return 0
   $count++; //increment

   if ($count < 0 || $count > count($rdmimg) - 1) //if out of range, reset
       $count = 0;

   setcookie("check_image", $count);

   //make sure the code below is echo $rdmimg[$count] (replace it with the existing echo $a)
   ```

Both methods will return a different image every time, but method 2 will cycle, while method 1 is just random without duplicates.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! They work flawlessly, and I think you really helped me understand the basics of cookie setting, which I was struggling with